# iOS which is the default UIColor for tabbar icon?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitabbar

I am changing properly tabbar icon color but I need sometimes to go back to default blue one. Which is the default blue color from palette? UIColor "cyan" and also "blue" are not! Thanks

```
colorIcon = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Comment: Can you post your actual code?

Comment: edited. I must set colorIcon as default one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you change the color of your tabbar icon, you could save the current color and use that variable to restore the original color.

```
UIColor *originalColor = tabBar.selectedTintColor;
[tabBar setSelectedTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Restore your original color:

```
[tabBar setSelectedTintColor:originalColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully and you will see that the color actually is a color-fade using some blue and some light blue or even white.

See this:

[image]

Comment: I see, but how to call that palette color or RGB values? Thanks